# CakePHP Custom Login & OPAuth

Tags: php, facebook, cakephp, authentication, oauth

I have successfully implemented Opauth for CakePHP for Google & Facebook.
On the original return, they write info to the database including auth_id & auth_method as well as being assigned as user_id.
This is working correctly
On all succeeding returns it should log the user in.
I also have a basic email & password login running at the same time.
To get the user I use:

```
$user = $this->User->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array('User.auth_id' => $this->data['auth']['uid'],
                                    'User.auth_method' => 2)));
```

This returns a user, but the following always returns false:

```
$this->Auth->login($user)
```

I have also tried

```
login($user['User']), login($user['User']['user_id'])
```

But does not work... Any hints?

Comment: please mention cakephp version

Comment: CakePHP version 2.5.4

Comment: have you checked cookbook for 2.5

Comment: Yes, it says to use the methods I have stated above, which aren't working

Comment: use $this->request->data instead of $user as mentioned on doc